# How to tell if my iPad is connected to WiFi using WPA3, WPA2, or no security at all?

Tags: ipad, ipados, wifi

In Settings > Wi-Fi, I tapped the i-in-circle info icon to get details on a network connection. But I did not notice any mention of what encryption might be in use.

Comment: Do you see a little lock right next to the `i`-symbol? That tells you if its encrypted or not.

Comment: @X_841 Yes, there is a padlock icon there. Thanks for the tip. But I’d still like to know the technical details of the connection, such as if WPA3 is in use.

Comment: Don't think there is a way on iOS without using a 3rd party app. Alternatively, a Mac would be able to determine what the security protocol is.

Comment: Do you own the Wi-Fi hotspot you are connecting to? Usually it has got a maintenance web site where all connected devices and connection types are listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If a Wi-Fi network has a lock next to its name, it's a password-protected network.

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204070

This is the only information given by iOS by the Settings app.

iOS APIs don’t provide this information to third party apps. [NEHotspotNetwork](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspotnetwork) provides various network information as described in that Apple documentation page (accessible if the app has the entitlement) but not the network security.

If your iOS device is jailbroken, you can install [GoodWifi](http://julioverne.github.io/description.html?id=com.julioverne.goodwifi). This shows the network security in the list of networks in the Settings app.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actually it’s possible to check this without jail breaking.
See:
https://download.developer.apple.com/iOS/iOS_Logs/WiFi_Logging_Instructions.pdf

Download and install the Wi-Fi for iOS profile without needing to reboot the device and you will be able to view diagnostics page in the Settings.
https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/profiles-and-logs/?platform=ios&name=WiFi

Comment: Both links are not publicly available. If you are allowed to, I recommend to post all necessary info inside your post, even the configuration profile as code.